# Multiple Screen Standby/Resume Problems

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, screen

I have a large widescreen monitor plugged into my Macbook which is running Lion. Since upgrading to Lion I've noticed that I can't resume from standby if my other monitor was plugged in when I closed the lid.

Everything works great - I close the lid and the computer enters standby like it is supposed to. Then when I open the screen the next morning, it just comes up with a lit, but dark screen. At this point, the only thing that seems to work is a hard reboot. I've tried unplugging the other monitor but that doesn't change it.

It is important to note that this does **not** happen if the monitor was not plugged in when the computer screen was closed. Also if I chose Sleep from the Apple menu, everything works great.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long delay on this answer, but since there were no other ideas, I'll answer with what I've done.

I simple unplug the monitor every night before putting the computer to sleep. Not anything fancy or technical, but it works for me.